# Number of users in a group

Tags: windows, active-directory, windows-server-2012

I've been searching for an answer to this all over the internet and I can't seem to find it. I created a group and added a lot of users in it. how can i find how many users (Number) do i have in the group?

Answer (score 0):

Found it after posting the question haha :

Start powershell
Run: Import-module ActiveDirectory
Run: (Get-ADGroupMember -Identity “GROUPNAME”).count (replace GROUPNAME with the group you want to count)